# Using a secondary internal drive as a 100% Ubuntu Installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have an empty hard drive that I want to get Ubuntu on for a dual boot system. I don't know how to just get it on that free drive without touching my Windows drive since both are showing on that screen.

I tried the automagic dual boot install option but it only took half of my HDD (no sliders are actually offered on that step) and then botched the installation with a known "third party drivers checkbox" error. I had to fix my drive, stop a GRUB terminal from booting up first, and now there's a residual Ubuntu marker that does nothing somewhere when I choose to boot to UEFI or from removable drives on that blue Windows screen.

So now that it's mostly fixed and I can't trust the auto install settings, how do I do all of those manual /root /boot / things just on the drive that I want them on? It's visible on the list but I can't just click on it and press Install and I'm not an expert on what all of those /sda entries and other stuff are supposed to mean.

Comment: You haven't said what release you're asking about, but I'd always opt for "*Something else*" (or the "Manual Partitioning*" option) so you can select partition(s) and drive(s) yourself.. ie. get exactly what you want.  The boot-loader is the only option you don't always have full control over (that can vary on release & system being installed; which you didn't specify).

Comment: 20.04.1. I didn't mention it because I thought it'd be a given or that even the latest doesn't really change any steps significantly. And yes, that Something Else page is the one giving me problems. Ubuntu works on my system just fine once it's installed. I just decided against it on my SSD.

Comment: Is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/590937) helpful for you?

Comment: Well first it made my brain explode. Then YES! Each drive has their own identifier names and directory chain of important assignments/operations. It also made a lot more sense after I went back to re-initialize the drive in Windows first (I unintialized it when I used diskpart to clean it). The link doesn't include that tidbit even though the installer half-recognizes the drive in that form anyway.